# Unable to format date inside object

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js, date-fns

I have some JavaScript tests and I have to write code that passes them.

The tests are these:

```js
beforeAll(async () => {
  availabilities = await getAvailabilities(new Date("2020-01-01 00:00"));
});

it("returns an Object", () => {
  expect(typeof availabilities === "object").toBe(true);
  expect(Array.isArray(availabilities)).toBe(false);
});

it("key is a date string with format YYYY/MM/DD", () => 
  expect(Object.keys(availabilities)[0]).toEqual("2020-01-01");
});

it("value is an Array", () => {
  expect(Object.values(availabilities)[0]).toEqual([]);
});
```

I have used `knex` as DB and made a selection with the following:

```
const response = await knexClient("events").select("starts_at", "ends_at");
```

But when I use `date-fns` to format the date

```
response = format(response[0], 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

It doesn't work.

I know that I can't format the response directly because it's an object but I don't know how to parse it.

Comment: For those of us that have never heard of knex, can you `console.log(response)` and tell us what that variable is. Your database isn't really relevant. Your data is what's relevant.

Comment: Please elaborate on "it doesn't work". Does test fail? Any other error?

Comment: Knex isn't really the problem. It returns a select inside an object. 

The problem is that i can't parse the object to format the dates that it contains.

@udalmik it doesn't pass the test provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using create function for format date

```
res=[ { starts_at: '2020-01-01T07:00:00.000Z' } ]
let final
let date = res.filter(res=>final=res.starts_at.split("T")[0].split("-")[2]+"/"+res.starts_at.split("T")[0].split("-")[1]+"/"+res.starts_at.split("T")[0].split("-")[0])
console.log(final);
```

Comment: It works. Kinda. 

If i give it a date as a string it works but i don't have the date as a string, it's an object containing a string.
'console.log(response);'

'[ { starts_at: '2020-01-01T07:00:00.000Z' } ]'

Comment: Sorry for my wrong solution now will check my edited solution, hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your answers but unfortunately it didn't work for me.

I used date-fns to format the time and I accessed it like this:

```
const response = await knexClient("events").select("starts_at");

var start = response[0].starts_at;  
var onlyDate = format(new Date(start), "yyyy-MM-dd");
var onlyTime = format(new Date(start), "H:mm");
var Object = {
  [onlyDate] : [onlyTime]
}
```

and it returns the date and the time exactly as I want them.